# Transform a function to add an array

Tags: jquery, foreach

I found here a code to create repeated fields in a form : 
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-3-extra-fields--wp-23821

I used it and it works perfectly, but now I need to expand it : instead of reapeating a field, I need to repeat a set of two fields, a select and an input.

The solution given in comment http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-3-extra-fields--wp-23821#comment-958708708 works, but for two fields of the same time.

The code is :

```
jQuery('.repeatable-add').click(function() {
    field = jQuery(this).closest('td').find('.custom_repeatable li:last').clone(true);
    fieldLocation = jQuery(this).closest('td').find('.custom_repeatable li:last');
    jQuery(input, field).val('').attr('name', function(index, name) {
        return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
            return Number(n) + 1;
        });
    })
    field.insertAfter(fieldLocation, jQuery(this).closest('td'))
    return false;
});
```

I did some search and understood I should create a variable before

```
var elements = ['input', 'select'] ;
```

and then loop for each element, at the level of jQuery(input, field) but I can't achieve a working code !

The HTML is :

```
<ul id="_transfer_extra-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable ui-sortable">
    <li>
         <span class="sort hndle ui-sortable-handle">|||</span>
         <select name="_transfer_extra[0][transfer_place]">
              <option value="">Select a value</option>
              <option value="453">Place1</option>
              <option value="462">Place2</option>
         </select>
         Price
         <input type="text" value="60" name="_transfer_extra[0][transfer_price]">
         <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<a class="repeatable-add button" href="#">+</a>
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above has a couple of problems:

- The JavaScript does not match the provided HTML (that should go inside a table with a `td`, otherwise the JS won't work because you are using a `closest("td")` to get the fields).
- There is a typo in here: `jQuery(input, field)`, it's missing some quotes as it should be `jQuery("input", field)`.

Once you correct those issues (and add the `forEach` to traverse the array with the elements to be updated), the code works just fine:

```js
var elements = ['input', 'select'] ;

$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.repeatable-add').click(function() {
    field = jQuery(this).closest('td').find('.custom_repeatable li:last').clone(true);
    fieldLocation = jQuery(this).closest('td').find('.custom_repeatable li:last');

    // for each of the element types, set the value to empty and change the name
    elements.forEach(function(el) {
      jQuery(el, field).val('').attr('name', function(index, name) {
        return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch, n) {
          return Number(n) + 1;
        });
      })
    });
    
    field.insertAfter(fieldLocation, jQuery(this).closest('td'))
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul id="_transfer_extra-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable ui-sortable">
        <li>
          <span class="sort hndle ui-sortable-handle">|||</span>
          <select name="_transfer_extra[0][transfer_place]">
            <option value="">Select a value</option>
            <option value="453">Place1</option>
            <option value="462">Place2</option>
          </select>
          Price
          <input type="text" value="60" name="_transfer_extra[0][transfer_price]"/>
          <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="repeatable-add button" href="#">+</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Notice that in the code, you update the value of the `name` for the text input, but not for the `select`, that will have the same for all its instances (which may be something that causes trouble later)

Comment: Thank you, actually I was not precise enough. The code is inside a td, but , I corrected the "quote" problem which helped, but the code is not adapted to my needs : 

only the "select" item is renumbered, into "_transfer_extra[1][transfer_place] and I need also 
_transfer_extra[0][transfer_price] to be incremented to 1. 

Works as coded, as the initial code was intended for one field only, and I don't understand how to make it increase the number for both select and input. 

Somehow, I need to modify jQuery("input", field) , and replace "input" by an array but I don't know how to do it ?

Comment: Oh, I understand now. One second, let me adapt the code

Comment: I updated the code so now the number in the `name` changes for both `select` and `input`. (notice that `forEach` works from IE9)

Comment: Thank you very much. It does work not work from within the WordPress Admin, but I know why and I can correct it (they have a specific way to call jQuery). I did test it on a single html page where it works perfectly ! 
Have a nice day.